# dynamically setting meta tags as per URL

Tags: .htaccess, facebook-graph-api, server-side, meta-tags

Lets I have a search engine which searches for the query specified in the URL as exemplified :-

```
1. xyz.com/apple-ipod-touch
2. xyz.com/apple-macbook-pro
3. xyz.com/reebok-shoes
```

Now, depending on the URL, I wish to set the meta tags of my pages.

Please note that I don't wish to change these meta-tags using javascript , as these have to be read by Facebook for publishing stream. So, I am expecting something which changes meta-tags in the server-side itself(like somehow through .htaccess). Is there any way to do the same ?

Any suggestions or links will do.

Please comment if I am unclear in asking my doubt.

Thanks !

Thanks !

Comment: Please note that all the URLs above will point to the same page

Comment: Will setting the meta tags using PHP, will be helpful in that case ?

Comment: Are the pages being creating dynamically?

Comment: Yeah, they are created dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pages are being created dynamically, than I would assume you're using some sort of database to store information pertaining each product. So when you make a call, just simply placing something along the lines like

```
<?
    $ogtitle = ($mysqlrow["product_title"])? $mysqlrow["product_title"] : "Use normal site title here";
?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$ogtitle;?>" />
```

This is assuming you are using PHP, but basic scenario for other server side languages as well.

Comment: I had the doubt whether facebook crawler would be able to read that PHP thing ?

Comment: When Facebook and other engines crawl your website, they are seeing as a person would if they right clicked on the page and viewed the source, they are just looking for the certain tags to label items and descriptions. They would never be able to see the server side coding which is what PHP is.